# How to open port 80 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, port

I want to open port 80 to allow HTTP connections on my EC2 server. But when I'm entering "telnet xx.xx.xx.xx  80" on a terminal the following is displayed

```
"Trying xx.xx.xx.xx..." 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

In AWS I've opened port 80 by defining an Inbound Rule on the Security group (only one security group is defined for this EC2 server)

[image]

[image]

I'm using the Public IPv4 address to make a telnet connection

[image]

Comment: Is there potentially firewall settings that need to also be disabled on your remote server or other settings through the console?
Give this a try (I do this to allow traffic to nginx on my servers):
`sudo apt-get install ufw`
`sudo ufw allow 80`

Comment: Do you have anything running on port 80? You can test by logging into the EC2 instance and running `curl localhost`. Are you connecting to the **Public IP address** of the instance? Have you modified the NACLs from their default "Allow All" settings?

Comment: I'm doing the telnet command from within EC2.  I connect via SSH to the EC2 server.  So, there is no firewall I guess.

Comment: When I do  "curl localhost"  the following message appears :  curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: This is a new EC2 server, and no software is installed yet.  And I'm connecting the the Public IPv4 address. see the screenshot.

Comment: I've not modified the NACL from it's default values

Comment: If there is nothing running on port 80 or any framework being bound to act as a server there nothing can respond? The point of port 80 is to host a WSGI, CGI, or web server like nginx to act as a protocol over http.

I am failing to understand your question.

Comment: If there is nothing listening on the server port 80 it could be open just unreponsive

Comment: Any luck testing with my solution?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you have a fresh install -- fresh installs do not have software listening over HTTP by default.

If there is no application listening on a port, incoming packets to that port will simply be rejected by the computer's operating system. Ports can be "closed" through the use of a firewall, which you have disabled, therefore the ports are open just unresponsive which makes them appear closed.

If the port is enabled in the firewall in the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow http
sudo reboot
```

and enabled in the AWS console as a rule, the port is open and just not responsive so it's seen as closed. By installing either nginx or something that binds to port 80, external requests to that port will be connected successfully, and the port will therefore be recognized as open. The reason ssh is recognized as open is because 1. it has firewall transparency, and 2. it is always listening (unlike port 80!).
Before installing nginx even though ports are allowed through the firewall:
[image]

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

([more nginx info](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nginx-start-stop-restart))

After: [image]

Simple port tester tool [here](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)